# Python (numpy or panda): How to enlarge the 2D array size by appending the values from the close boundary values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example. I have a 2D array:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

And I want it becomes:

```
1 1 2 3 3 
1 1 2 3 3
4 4 5 6 6
7 7 8 9 9
7 7 8 9 9
```

And then loop this process until the size becomes 9x9 2D array.
Thanks!

Comment: Try `np.pad()` with `edge` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for numpy's [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) function :

```
initial_array = np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3,3))
desired_shape = (9, 9)

number_of_repeat_axis0 = desired_shape[0] // initial_array.shape[0]
number_of_repeat_axis1 = desired_shape[1] // initial_array.shape[1]

tmp = np.repeat(initial_array , number_of_repeat_axis0, axis = 0)
output = np.repeat(tmp, number_of_repeat_axis1, axis = 1)

'''
returns :
[[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6]
 [4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6]
 [4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6]
 [7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9]
 [7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9]
 [7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9]]
'''
```

But this will repeat all your data, including that in the middle of your array. If you only want the extremal values to be repeated, simply change it to :

```
tmp = np.repeat(initial_array , [4,1,4], axis = 0)
output = np.repeat(tmp, [4,1,4], axis = 1)

'''
returns :
[[1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 5 6 6 6 6]
 [7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9]
 [7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9]
 [7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9]
 [7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9]]
'''
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but It seems this is not consistent with my question. I think the code should be more complex. The original 3x3 array is located in the center, and enlarge it to all directions.